# Objective-C equivalent of internal(set) in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, setter, access-control

The `internal(set)` access modifier in Swift allows a property to be changed within the same module, but not from the outside. I'm curious about whether it has an Objective-C equivalent, and how I can implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no equivalent in Objective-C.

But you can *hide* the setter outside from the module (Framework). For example:

`MyObject.h`: as **Public** header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyObject : NSObject
// `readonly` for public
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *myProp;
@end
```

`MyObject-Internal.h`: as **Project** header

```
#import "MyObject.h"

@interface MyObject ()
// NOT `readonly` for internal
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myProp;
@end
```

Then, you can use `MyObject-Internal.h` in `.m` codes inside the module.